# Do select() or send() sometimes fail?

Tags: c, sockets, select

I'm having a problem with AF_INET sockets.

I have two processes that communicate through sockets. I'm using `send()`, `recv()` and `select()`.

The thing is that sometimes, when I send the first message from one to the other, it stucks, it's like the `select()` never realize of the message...or it never gets there, I don't know.

At first, I checked my code debugging it, and I found that when I do it, it NEVER fails. It seems it fails (sometimes) just when I execute on the console.

Any ideas?

EDIT - 2. I'll put almost all the code.

This is the main code

```
void main() {
    t_list *levelsList = getLevelsList();
    char *levelName = (char *) malloc(MAXSIZE);
    t_level_address *addresses = (t_level_address *) malloc(sizeof(t_level_address));
    t_dictionary *levelsMap = dictionary_create();

    levelsMap = getLevelsMap();

    char** port = (char*) malloc(MAXSIZE);
    int i;
    t_dictionary *levels_queues = dictionary_create();

    for (i = 0; i < list_size(levelsList); i++) {
        pthread_t *t = (pthread_t*) malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));
        levelName = (char *) list_get(levelsList, i);
        addresses = (t_level_address*) dictionary_get(levelsMap, levelName);
        port = string_split(addresses->planificador, DOSPUNTOS);
        t_scheduler_queue *scheduler_queue = (t_scheduler_queue*) malloc(sizeof(t_scheduler_queue));
        scheduler_queue->blocked_queue = queue_create();
        scheduler_queue->character_queue = queue_create();
        scheduler_queue->port = port[1];
        dictionary_put(levels_queues, levelName, scheduler_queue);
        pthread_create(t, NULL, (void *) planificador, (t_scheduler_queue*) scheduler_queue);
    }

    free(levelName);
    free(addresses);
    free(levelsList);

    int sock; /* fd del listener*/
    int connectlist[MAXQUEUE]; /* array de sockets conectados */
    fd_set socks; /* lista de fds */
    int highsock; /* Highest #'d file descriptor, needed for select() */

    int readsocks; /* Number of sockets ready for reading */

    /* Obtain a file descriptor for our "listening" socket */
    sock = socketServer(PORT);
    listen(sock, MAXQUEUE);
    highsock = sock;
    memset((char *) &connectlist, 0, sizeof(connectlist));

    while (1) {
        build_select_list(sock, connectlist, highsock, &socks);
        readsocks = select(FD_SETSIZE, &socks, (fd_set *) 0, (fd_set *) 0, NULL);
        if (readsocks < 0) {
            perror("select");
            exit(1);
        } else
            accionar(sock, connectlist, highsock, socks, levelsMap, levels_queues);
    }
}


void accionar(int sock, int connectlist[], int highsock, fd_set socks, t_dictionary *levelsMap, t_dictionary *levels_queues) {
    int listnum;

    // Devuelvo el valor correspondiente al fd listener para primero gestionar conexiones nuevas.
    if (FD_ISSET(sock,&socks)){
        orquestador(levelsMap, handle_new_connection(sock, connectlist, highsock, socks), levels_queues);
    }
    for (listnum = 0; listnum < MAXQUEUE; listnum++) {
        if (FD_ISSET(connectlist[listnum],&socks))
            orquestador(levelsMap, connectlist[listnum], levels_queues);
    }
}

void orquestador(t_dictionary *levelsMap, int *fd, t_dictionary *levels_queues) {
    char *response = (char *) malloc(MAXSIZE); //CHECK LENGTH
    printf("Realizo el pop\n");
    response = recieveMessage(fd);
    if(!string_starts_with(response, BROKEN)){
        executeResponse(response, levelsMap, fd, levels_queues);
    }
}
```

And here is the library I made.

```
void setnonblocking(int sock) {
    int opts;

    opts = fcntl(sock, F_GETFL);
    if (opts < 0) {
        perror("fcntl(F_GETFL)");
        exit(1);
    }
    opts = (opts | O_NONBLOCK);
    if (fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, opts) < 0) {
        perror("fcntl(F_SETFL)");
        exit(1);
    }
    return;
}

void build_select_list(int sock, int connectlist[], int highsock, fd_set *socks) {
    int listnum; /* Current item in connectlist for for loops */

    /* First put together fd_set for select(), which will
    consist of the sock veriable in case a new connection
    is coming in, plus all the sockets we have already
    accepted. */

    /* FD_ZERO() clears out the fd_set called socks, so that
    it doesn't contain any file descriptors. */

    FD_ZERO(socks);

    /* FD_SET() adds the file descriptor "sock" to the fd_set,
    so that select() will return if a connection comes in
    on that socket (which means you have to do accept(), etc. */

    FD_SET(sock, socks);

    /* Loops through all the possible connections and adds
    those sockets to the fd_set */

    for (listnum = 0; listnum < MAXQUEUE; listnum++) {
        if (connectlist[listnum] != 0) {
            FD_SET(connectlist[listnum], socks);
            if (connectlist[listnum] > highsock)
                highsock = connectlist[listnum];
        }
    }
}

int *handle_new_connection(int sock, int connectlist[], int highsock, fd_set socks) {
    int listnum; /* Current item in connectlist for for loops */
    int *connection = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)); /* Socket file descriptor for incoming connections */
    int finish = 0;

    /* We have a new connection coming in! We'll
    try to find a spot for it in connectlist. */
    connection = accept(sock, NULL, NULL );
    if (connection < 0) {
        perror("accept");
        exit(1);
    }
    setnonblocking(connection);
    for (listnum = 0; (listnum < MAXQUEUE) && (finish != 0); listnum++)
        if (connectlist[listnum] == 0) {
            printf("\nConnection accepted: FD=%d; Slot=%d\n", connection, listnum);
            connectlist[listnum] = connection;
            finish = 1;
        }
    return connection;
}

int *handle_new_connection_scheduler(int sock, int connectlist[], int highsock, fd_set socks) {
    int listnum; /* Current item in connectlist for for loops */
    int *connection = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)); /* Socket file descriptor for incoming connections */
    int finish = 0;

    /* We have a new connection coming in! We'll
    try to find a spot for it in connectlist. */
    connection = accept(sock, NULL, NULL );
    if (connection < 0) {
        perror("accept");
        exit(1);
    }
    setnonblocking(connection);
    return connection;
}

void deal_with_data(int listnum, int connectlist[MAXQUEUE]) {
    char *buffer = (char*) malloc(MAXSIZE); /* Buffer for socket reads */
    int fd = connectlist[listnum];
    buffer = recieveMessage(fd);
    if (string_starts_with(buffer, BROKEN)) {
        /* Connection closed, close this end
        and free up entry in connectlist */
        printf("\nConnection lost: FD=%d; Slot=%d\n", connectlist[listnum], listnum);
        close(connectlist[listnum]);
        connectlist[listnum] = 0;
    } else {
        /**
        * HAGO ALGO
        */
    }
}

void read_socks(int sock, int connectlist[], int highsock, fd_set socks) {
    int listnum;

    // Devuelvo el valor correspondiente al fd listener para primero gestionar conexiones nuevas.
    if (FD_ISSET(sock,&socks))
        handle_new_connection(sock, connectlist, highsock, socks);

    for (listnum = 0; listnum < MAXQUEUE; listnum++) {
        if (FD_ISSET(connectlist[listnum],&socks))
            deal_with_data(listnum, connectlist);
    }
}

int selecting() {
    int sock; /* fd del listener*/
    int connectlist[MAXQUEUE]; /* array de sockets conectados */
    fd_set socks; /* lista de fds */
    int highsock; /* Highest #'d file descriptor, needed for select() */

    int port; /* The port number after conversion from ascport */
    struct sockaddr_in server_address; /* bind info structure */
    int reuse_addr = 1; /* Used so we can re-bind to our port
                           while a previous connection is still
                           in TIME_WAIT state. */
    int readsocks; /* Number of sockets ready for reading */

    /* Obtain a file descriptor for our "listening" socket */
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    /* So that we can re-bind to it without TIME_WAIT problems */
    setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuse_addr, sizeof(reuse_addr));

    /* Set socket to non-blocking with our setnonblocking routine */
    setnonblocking(sock);

    /* Get the address information, and bind it to the socket */
    port = atoi(port); /* le paso el puerto */
    memset((char *) &server_address, 0, sizeof(server_address));
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY );
    server_address.sin_port = port;
    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address)) < 0) {
        perror("bind");
        close(sock);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Set up queue for incoming connections. */
    listen(sock, MAXQUEUE);

    highsock = sock;
    memset((char *) &connectlist, 0, sizeof(connectlist));

    while (1) { /* Main server loop - forever */
        build_select_list(sock, connectlist, highsock, &socks);
        readsocks = select(FD_SETSIZE, &socks, (fd_set *) 0, (fd_set *) 0, NULL);
        if (readsocks < 0) {
            perror("select");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (readsocks == 0) {
            /* Nothing ready to read, just show that we're alive */
            printf(".");
            fflush(stdout);
        } else
            read_socks(sock, connectlist, highsock, socks);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you checking all error codes from the call you're making?

Comment: Stream or datagram? Are you assuming uninitialized data will be `0` initialized?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [FAQ] soon. A question like this is practically unanswerable as written. There are endless ways to get the code wrong. To get much help, you are going to need to post an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) which shows what you are doing in as little space as possible. The internet runs on system calls like `send()`, `recv()`, and `select()`; the chances of there being a problem with those (as opposed to with your code) is approximately nil. Assume that you are misusing them and that's causing the odd behaviour you see.

Comment: What's `FD_SETSIZE` ? Show us its value. Where are  the `FD_ZERO`  and the `FD_SET` ?

Comment: It seems that FD_SETSIZE is 1024 in sys/select.h

Comment: The first argument to select() should be the maximum of all the socket fd values select() is watching, plus one.  (It looks like that was maybe the intent of "highsock", but since highsock is being passed by value I don't think that logic is working)

Comment: [`select()` isn't broken.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html)

Comment: So, could be the "highsock"?

Comment: @nouney FD_SETSIZE is a standard macro for the largest fd select can handle. This use is fine, albeit it could be inefficient, it's not the culprit here.

Comment: Is there any more code I should show to you, guys? =(